# $(u_{2n})$,$(u_{2n+1})$,$(u_{3n+1})$ converge $\underset{???}{\Rightarrow}(u_n)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Let $(u_n)_{n_\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}$.

We know that $(u_{2n})$, $(u_{2n+1})$ and $(u_{3n+1})$ converge.

The question is to know whether $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

---

**/!\ I am not looking for the detailed answer to this question, please do not post it.**

Something is bugging me in the above question. If a sequence converges then all its sub-sequences converge towards the same limit.

> Therefore we have $l\in\mathbb{C}$ such that :
>
> Let $e>0,\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\geq n_0, |U_{2n}-l|\leq
>  e\text{ and }|U_{2n+1}-l|\leq e$
>
> Thus $\forall n\geq 2n_0+1, |U_n-l|\leq e$
>
> Therefore $(u_n)_{n_\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

What is bugging me in the above is that we didn't use the convergence of $(u_{3n+1})$ in the proof. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes.  What you missed is that $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ can converge without converging to the same thing.  You need to show that, if they converge to different things, than $u_{3n+1}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: You're working the problem backwards by assuming that the sequence _is_ convergent, so that its subsequence converges to the same limit.  Suppose that $u_n=\frac1n$ if $n$ is odd and $u_n=\frac{n+1}n$ if $n$ is even.  Then this sequence satisfies the hypotheses that don't mention $u_{3n+1}$, but it's clearly not convergent.

Comment: @Aaron Oh thanks, I feel so dumb :c .

Comment: @Aaron What happens when the answer is given in the comments ? Do you post it as an answer, or ... ?

Comment: It's actually somewhat bad form of me to post a complete answer in comments, as it means the problem will be left marked as unanswered.  If you feel that I have sufficiently answered your question, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Please do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  What you missed is that $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ can converge without converging to the same thing.  You need to show that, if they converge to different things, then $u_{3n+1}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: lol, yes Pedro.  Fixing my grammar.

Answer (score 3):

$(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2n+1})$ might converge to two different numbers, so that the sequence as a whole does not converge.  But the third sequence alternates between even and odd indices, so it would diverge in such a case.